# How can I sort incoming data based on date column to select only latest date data for IDs?

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

ADF/Data Flow--
I want to sort my incoming data based on the date column. My requirement is to take only latest date data(previous date data) for the ID, and ID can be duplicate with different dates.
I have tries sorting based on both id and date column but it is not working for all the records.
Can someone please help me to get this sorted in Data flow of Azure data factory!

I need to pick only those IDs which are having latest date from a Date column.Also how can I extract only day from date type column? example '23-05-2023' I want on 23 from this date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pick only the latest date data for each ID, you can use the `Aggregate` transformation and group by  `ID` column and use the `Max` function to get the maximum date value for each group. To extract only the day from a date type column, you can use the `Derived Column` transformation and use the `dayOfMonth()` function to extract the day value from the date column. Below are the steps.

- Source transformation is taken with sample input.

[image]

- Then Aggregate Transformation is taken and aggregate settings is given as,

```
group by: id
aggregates: date = max(date)
```

[image]

This groups the data by the `ID` column, and gets the maximum `Date` value for each group.

- Then derived column transformation is taken and create a new column called for `Day` and give the expression as `split(toString(date),'-')[3]` or `dayOfMonth(date)` to extract the day value from `date` column
  [image]

**Derived column Transformation -Output:**

[image]

**Dataflow expression**

```
source(output(
id as short,
date as date
),
allowSchemaDrift: true,
validateSchema: false,
ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
dateFormats: ['dd-MM-yyyy']) ~> source1
source1 aggregate(groupBy(id),
date =  max(date)) ~> aggregate1
aggregate1 derive(Day =  split(toString(date),'-')[3],
column1 =  dayOfMonth(date)) ~> derivedColumn1
```

Comment: Hi Aswin, thank you for the answer. I have also used Aggreagte stage, but the issue I am facing is, in SINK stage I am not getting my all columns. Suppose I have 10 columns and I am doing group by ID and aggregate on max(date_column), so I do not want any new column for date, it should populate the latest date in the same column only, and I should get all 10 columns in output. But that is not happening. I am only getting 2 columns at the output. My flow is: Source-Filter-derived column-alter row-sort-sink. where should I put my aggregate stage?

Comment: Okay, In order to get all columns, you can use join transformation after aggregate transformation. In Join transformation, give Left stream as aggragate1 and right stream as source1 and take `left outer join`. Give the joining conditions as` id=id` and `date=date`. By this way you can get all columns for that row